# Recovering google authenticator codes on a broken phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, google, google-authenticator

So recently my galaxy s3's screen broke and I lost my Google authentactor app. I thought I had all the backup codes stored in my laptop but when I went to recover them I found out that one of my family members decided to go on a cleaning spree and deleted a bunch of files because they "didn't know what they for" So my question is there anyway to recover the codes off of my old phone?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recover codes from this app as it produces new ones every minute and doesn't provide **Backup codes** functionality. Perhaps, file recovery software might help you in recovering them from laptop but that's more like an opportunity lost here.

I always have my backup codes saved in a cloud in case any tragedy occurs.

Answer (score 1):

you could flash a custom recovery to your phone such as Clockworkmod, reboot into recovery and from there you can use ADB to pull /data/data directory, in there would be the google authenticator app.

if you got another S3 you could flash a custom recovery and then push the /data/data directory(after installing the app again) and google authenticator would then work as it did on the old phone.

its possible to flash a custom recovery without a working screen as it uses the volume keys and the power button.